# Google Tag Manager JSON should be committed to version control?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, appsflyer

I'm integrating Google Tag Manager in my project and got everything up.
However I'm not sure whether JSON (`GTM-XXXX` JSON file) should be committed or not.
I checked the code and noticed some ids and I'm not if this file is similar to `google-services.json` and must not be added/committed to git.
What is the correct approach?

Comment: What you mean with 'committed'?

Comment: GTM-XXXX is your container Id, which should be part of your installation scripts. We usually add it to the index.html and is usually committed to version control.

Comment: committed to any version control